# Map iterator vs. manual

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, iterator

I was trying to compare 2 techniques of filling maps, one with iterators and one without. I have heard iterators make it faster, but how?

```
//With Iterator
map<int, int>::iterator insert = fibHash.begin();
fibHash.insert(begin, pair<int, int> (n, fib_val));

//Without iterator
fibHash.insert(pair<int, int> (n, fib_val));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first form, where you provide an iterator, has the *potential* to be faster at runtime -- but only if you pick a good iterator, and even then only if your implementation uses the hint.  The iterator you send to `insert` is just a hint.  `insert` doesn't necessarily insert the element there, since a `map` is a sorted container.  Rather, the iterator can be used by the implementation as a starting point for when it looks for where it *will* insert the element.

So, if you pass it a well-chosen iterator (which `begin()` often will not be), using the version of `insert` which takes the hint iterator, you could theoretically approach amortized constant time for inserts, whereas with the non-hint version you're looking at `O(log n)` for inserts.

Comment: So, if I want to sequentially add elements at position [1] then [2] then [3] ... [n], would using the iterator be faster?

Comment: @Josh you are not adding elements at a certain position. You are telling the map "I think this is the best position for this element". The map itself can only add the element where it fits according to a strict weak ordering relation.

Comment: Sorry I meant with a key [1] [2] [3] [4] in a series to [n], then would it be faster?

Comment: @Josh:  Using the iterator here would be faster if you happen to insert them in ascending (using `.end()`) or descending (using `.begin()`) order.  You don't typically insert items in sorted order already though, so *in general* I would populate a map using the `insert(pair(key,value))` form, not the `insert(iter, pair(key,value))` form.

Comment: Also, are you sure you're not micro-optimizing prematurely?

Comment: Well I want to store values in the map which are reflected by their keys (Fibonacci series). Since I need to store their answers like fib[1] = 1, fib[2] = 2, fib[3] = 3...

Comment: Sure, but have you profiled your code under a release build and determined that `O(log n)` inserts to a `map` are an actual bottleneck in your code that you need to fix?

Comment: @JohnDibling: Are you sure about the *amortized constant time* bit. I understand that you put amortized there to cope with the internal reshuffling operations to keep the tree balanced, but I don't know whether the rebalance operations complexity vs frequency ratio is good enough to tend toward O(N).

Comment: @MatthieuM.:  The amoritized constant time is really just theoretical.  If you happen to pass it the perfect iterator every time, and it just so happens that rebalancing is never required, then inserts should, in theory, approach constant time.  Will this ever be the case in the real world?  Probably not, but you can't really make any reasonable observations about the *actual* time complexity of inserts until you actually run the thing with real data.

Comment: You are right to observe this though, and I've made a small edit to clarify the theoretical nature of the hinted inserts.  Oh, and thanks for the grammar & spelling edits. :)

Comment: Anther observation:  The whole theoretical constant time thing could be thrown completely out the window if a particular implementation chooses to ignore the hint.  The Standard, I believe, doesn't require an implementation to use the hint at all, so that would be a legitimate implementation.  I guess the moral of the story is don't rely on the hint to save your application.

Comment: @JohnDibling: If no rebalancing were required, then you would achieve *constant time*; *amortized* is only used for operations that are *in average* O(1) but sometimes not (like `std::vector<>::push_back`). I was thinking that you may have a theoretical result about the average time for some insertions (like a sorted vector where you would always passed `end()`).

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you have to bear in mind that `std::map` is an ordered structure, so you cannot place elements at arbitrary position. A certain element can only be placed in a certain position relative to others, according to a [strict weak ordering relation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html) (a less-then relation satisfying certain conditions).

The first variant takes an iterator as a hint for a good position for the element, and only makes the insertion faster (amortized constant time) if the insertion happens next to the input iterator. Otherwise, the complexity is the same as the second variant (logarithmic).

The first variant uses the first argument as a hint, and tries the insertion. If the hint is good, then less comparisons are required to find the right position for insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what has been said: If you are concerned with speed, also consider the new C++11 methods [std::map::emplace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/emplace/) and [std::map::emplace_hint](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/emplace_hint/) for inserting elements into a `std::map`. Instead of passing a copy of a Key/Value pair to the container, emplace passes only the arguments for creating this pair **in-place** at the right position. This can save you expensive copies (although in your int,int example this wouldn't make much of a difference, as opposed to larger data structures such as matrices, etc.).

```
std::map<int,int> MyMap;
MyMap.emplace(5,10); // passing 5,10 to ctor of std::pair<const int,int> in-place
MyMap.insert(std::pair<const int,int>(5,10)); // construct a std::pair<const int,int> and pass it to insert, such that it creates a copy in the right location within the map

//similarly with the 'hint' methods
MyMap.emplace_hint(MyMap.end(),6,20);
MyMap.insert(MyMap.end(),std::pair<const int,int>(6,20));
```

Btw., `std::map<int,int>::value_type` is really a `std::pair<const int,int>`, not a `std::pair<int,int>`.

Answer (score -2):

Iterator is a Design Pattern, something all programmers should take into account. Yes, iterators aren't really faster, but cleaner, they allow you to "iterate" data structures in a safe and clean way, so you shouldn't worry about messing with the real information.

In this particular case, u are only inserting one value at a time, so iterators aren't really the "fastest" solution, just happens to be that certain functions can use it as well.

In Your first example, you are inserting a value at the "begin"ing of the data structure, and the iterator is helping you to determine the position.

In the second one, you are just inserting the value at the end, or in the default intersion position, so you really don't need an iterator for that.

Comment: ``std::map`` is an ordered structure, so the insertion is not at the beginning or the end. The insertion happens, then the map has to find the correct place for the inserted element.